# Content-Security-Policy does not allow styles to load and prevent functions (Angular 13)

Tags: angular, angular-material, content-security-policy, email-verification

I have this Angular app (Angular 13) Which I use to verify emails using firebase. It worked fine in localhost (also in Google Cloud Platform) but when I added meta directive for it stops showing any styles and stopped mail verification. It also shows this error.

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-dX2wiAFyhHetcI5CravRZJdRu/GpH759nUhgazh2/q0='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Styles are added using Angular/material 13. This is csp meta tag.

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; connect-src 'self';">
```

Dependencies of the project are

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.36",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.11",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "firebase": "^7.15.5",
    "google-auth-library": "^6.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.1.9",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  }
```

I tried only using . Only downloaded fonts in the assests folder appeared. What Should I do? I have been stuck in here weeks.

Comment: U can try this <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; img-src https://* 'self' data:;">

Comment: Doesn't it violate the whole point of using CSP in the app. and yes, https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37631 according to this issue, it is way to use CSP in angular

Answer (score 0):

Use Nonces or Hashes (recommended for inline styles). Read about it to implement.

Thanks!